# What can I use as a substitute for Nori Wrapper on a Chocolate Dessert Sushi?

Tags: chocolate, sushi

I'd like to make a chocolate dessert sushi but I'm stuck trying to come up with a substitute for nori *or* rice paper.  I know some people like to use plastic chocolate like in this [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2688/how-can-i-make-a-chocolate-cup-that-looks-like-the-seaweed-on-a-sushi-roll).

However I'd like to do something different to compliment the chocolate on the inside of the roll.  Nori and ricepaper don't seem like they would work well for a dessert.

So if anyone has an idea, I'd love to hear it.

As a *bonus*, has anyone tried using something other than coco rice krispies for crunchy?  They tend to get soggy and lose their crunch if you wait too long to eat them.

Comment: Have you tried actual nori?  It could work with the chocolate.

Answer (score 7):

Green fruit leather makes a good substitute for nori in dessert "sushi" rolls, if you're going for something that reminds people of sushi without being creepily realistic. (I recently made a variation of [these dessert sliders](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/310185493055634679/) for Independence Day and they were a little too realistic for people).

Comment: Why green? If it's a dessert, surely one could use whatever flavor fits the profile of the dessert.

Comment: Sure, but nori (dried seaweed) is what is being replaced and nori is green.

Comment: I think most people would say that the nori on sushi is black... or at least a very dark green. Most "green" fruit leather is more like Granny Smith apple green.

Comment: Dark green, yes, but even a lighter green reminds us of the nori to a degree, just like the other items in a dessert "sushi" usually remind us of the other sushi ingredients. If you're prioritizing taste above the similarity in appearance to sushi, something else (like the plastic chocolate mentioned by the OP) might be better.

Comment: Can fruit leather be made very thin?  As to the color, I'm not particular.  Strawberry or cherry flavors would work well for instance.

Comment: @Maelish I'm guessing the best option for "fruit leather" is the  American brand named "[Fruit Roll-Ups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_Roll-Ups)" or "Fruit By the Foot" (or the similar generic option). They are generally very thin - 1 mm or so - and can easily be used in this application. If you're not in the US, they may have similar products locally.

Comment: It can also be made easily at home with a dehydrator.  When I was young my mother even made it sun-dried.

Comment: I suspect a too-thick leather could be pounded thinner without losing much.

Comment: @Maelish : yes, if you make your own.  My mom makes it from pumpkin, and it's almost dissolve in your mouth as it's so thin, but I've never tried biting into it to see if it'd be too tough for this use.

Answer (score 1):

Edible cellophane comes to mind - I imagine you can add food colouring for the right shade. Here's a recipe from Heston Blumenthal: http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2011/dec/14/salted-butter-caramels-edible-wrappers-recipe

Comment: Is it durable enough to withstand the rolling process of making sushi?

Comment: Depends, I suppose. I wrapped those caramels with it, and twisted the ends to seal and they didn't break apart.